# Insert urls in WebBackForwardList of a webview

Tags: java, android, webview, browser-history

I work on a little browser created with webview. What I try now it's to add multi tabs feature on it.

I need to insert previous link in current BackForwardList, but I can't fin annything about this. I tried to call super.onPageFinished on pagestart to avoid load all of links, but not work. How can I insert a link in the back list?
Thank you for your time!